# How to calculate the summation of pairwise minima of two ranges with standard formulas?

Tags: google-sheets

### Problem statement

I'd like to calculate the following formula in a Google Spreadsheet, where **x** and **y** are both ranges of n rows and 1 column and *t* is a variable, using only standard formulas:

[image: f(t,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\sum{min(tx_i,y_i)}]

### Current situation

Right now I'm feeding x (say, `A1:A10`), y (say, `B1:B10`) and t (say, `D1`) to a custom function (`myFunction(t, x, y)`, see below), but executing scripts is rather performance intensive, so I'd like to know if there is a way to make this calculation without using a custom function.

```js
function myFunction(t, x, y)
{
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        var xi = parseInt(x[i]);
        var yi = parseInt(y[i]);
        sum += Math.min(t * xi, yi);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

In this example, E1 would become: `=myFunction(D1, A1:A10, B1:B10)`

### Desired situation

I am looking for something like `=SUM(MIN(D1 * A1:A10, B1:B10))`, but a confirmation or an educated guess that this is not possible is of course also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to test, but I think that the following formula can do what you need.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ARRAYFORMULA(D1 * A1:A10) < B1:B10; ARRAYFORMULA(D1 * A1:A10); B1:B10)))
```

**UPDATE**

Indeed, a better approach is commented by [Jelle Fresen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212115/jelle-fresen), eliminating unnecessary redundancy.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D1 * A1:A10 < B1:B10; D1 * A1:A10; B1:B10)))
```

Comment: Very close, but not yet correct. However, using the ARRAYFORMULA is definitely the right answer. After some reading about it [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/71291) and some experimenting, I found the right solution:
`=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A10 * D1 < B1:B10, A1:A10 * D1, B1:B10)))`.
If you edit you're answer to include the correct solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: I hope it was useful.

Comment: I owe you my apologies for saying your first answer was incorrect, it was in fact entirely correct. When I tested it, I duplicated the formula with the fill handle. However, I forgot to add $'s to the indices, so the output was only incorrect because I fed it with the wrong input. My apologies. If I could downvote my first comment, I would.

Comment: No problem! as I mentioned, I could not perform tests on the first answer. What is important is that a solution was reached. However, thank you very much.